# Unable to update ListView using Observer Pattern implementation

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to android and java. I'm doing an activity that parses XML and shows the content in different pages(pagination). While parsing, I check if I already have as many as 5 elements(number of elements on a page), and call an update function (code shown below). Ideally, as soon as the parser parses 5 elements I should get the listview on my screen, which doesnt happen. Help!!!

```
public class FeedActivity extends Activity 
           implements OnGestureListener, OnTouchListener, FeedDataListener {
    ......     
    private void doit() {
        ...
        feedAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, R.layout.pagination1, 
                                                feedListPage.getFeedList());
        lv.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
        ...
    }

    public void update(FeedItemList fil, int page) {
        if (feedList == null) {
            feedList = fil;
            doit();
        }
        else {
            feedList.getFeedList().clear();
            feedList.setFeedList(fil.getFeedList());
            feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            if (fi != null) flist.addFeedItem(fi);
            if (flist.getSize() % 5 == 0)
                 l.update(flist,
                          (int) Math.ceil((float) flist.getSize() / (float) 2));
        } else if (fi != null) {
            if (itemSubElements.contains(localName)) {
                fi.setElement(_tmpItem, html2text(_tmpValue));
                _tmpItem = null;
                _tmpValue = "";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the url http://androidworkz.com/2010/08/13/smart-list-adapter-tutorial-singleton-oberservable-list-objects-and-how-they-can-improve-your-app/

Thanks

Comment: Site is dead.  Way back machine URL: http://web.archive.org/web/20120606182235/http://androidworkz.com/2010/08/13/smart-list-adapter-tutorial-singleton-oberservable-list-objects-and-how-they-can-improve-your-app